# Testing with Laravel/Lumen facade

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, lumen

So, I'm trying to write a unit test for a piece of code that uses a facade, and it looks like this:

```
public function test() {
  MYFACADE::doSomething();
}
```

and in the unit test, I am trying to mock the facade call:

```
MYFACADE::shouldReceive('doSomething')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(false);
```

The only problem with this is that when Laravel tries to make an instance of underling class for the `MYFACADE`, it will of course run the constructor, and right there, is hardcoded database connection call. So without changing my facade, and removing database connection from the constructor of the facade class, is there any way to mock facade call without running the constructor of facade ?

UPDATE:
Rest of the setup:

Facade class

```
class MyFacade extends Facade 
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() 
    { 
        return 'myfacade'; 
    }
}
```

app.php

```
$app->register(App\Providers\MyServiceProvider::class);
class_alias('App\Facades\MyFacade', 'MYFACADE');
```

Service provider:

```
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {

        $this->app->bind('myfacade', function()
        {
            return new myClasThatDoesSomething();
        });
    }
}
```

The underlying class used by facade

```
class myClasThatDoesSomething
{
   public function __construct()  
    {
       // opens db connection here  
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {

    }
}
```

example class that uses facade:

```
class TestClass 
{
   public function testMethod()
   {
       $returnValue = MYFACADE::doSomething();
       return $returnValue;
   }
}
```

Unit test that checks if the testMethod() returns 'testValue';

```
MYFACADE::shouldReceive('doSomething')
            ->once()
            ->andReturn('testValue');   

$instance = new TestClass();
$value = $instance->testMethod();
$this->assertEquals('testValue', $value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/facades) reads:

> Facades provide a "static" interface to classes that are available in the application's service container.

Please make sure your `MYFACADE` follows this pattern. There is no room for constructor, databases, etc. If you test `MYFACADE::doSomething()` you should mock all other classes that are being used by the function.

Secondly, the following piece of code

```
MYFACADE::shouldReceive('doSomething')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn(false);
```

mocks the facade itself to test something else that **uses** `MYFACADE::doSomething()`. It should return an instance of `Mockery` which returns `false` wherever `MYFACADE::doSomething()` is being called within the test.

**EDIT:**

Laravel's Facade mock implementation instantiates the underlaying class, which allow to test services with thin constructors. Although it is the best practice, it may not always be possible to do. Assuming you cannot move DB connection logic from the constructor, your best bet will be to mock the service manually:

```
public function testTestMethod()
{
    MYFACADE::swap(\Mockery::mock()
        ->shouldReceive('doSomething')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn('testValue')
        ->getMock()
    );

    $instance = new \App\TestClass();
    $value = $instance->testMethod();
    $this->assertEquals('testValue', $value);
}
```

Comment: You are right about the second part, I am actually testing something else, so it works in that context. The constructor part that I was talking about is actually, the constructor of the class that the facade is created for. So, when Laravel defines the binding for the Facade it will create a new instance of the underlying class. Inside that class is the database call which is unnecessary in the unit test.

Comment: @Zed, if your facade instantiates the class instead of fetching the instance from container, there is nothing you can do but fix the code. TDD approach address this issue. If you like to unittest your code, you need to write testable code. Happy to show how to do that, if you add example of the code to your question.

Comment: Well, my service provider contains this inside the register method(): `$this->app->bind('myfacade', function()
        {
            return new myClassThatDoThings();
        });` And inside the `myClassThatDoThings` constructor is the problematic database call. It's shame that I can't somehow replace this `myClassThatDoThings` object inside the unit test.

Comment: It is shame to call service provider a facade ;)  Naming it so does not make it work as a facade. I don't see where is your `doSomething` method here, an to be honest code examples are barely readable in the comment format. Could you edit the actual question with example of the **code you are trying to test**.

Comment: OK, I edited the question, I think its everywhere there. Keep in mind that it doesn't contain real logic, just enough to get the idea of what i'm trying to do. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, now it clearly shows where the problem lies. I have updated the answer. Hopefully it helps and the code is self-explanatory.